The module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'
I have a working console application in local that runs exchangeonline using CertificateThumbprint, AppID, & Organization as Credentials. The problem is when converted on function app and run locally, i received an error when importing the exchangeonline module:
[2024-10-07T03:46:44.417Z] Error during Import-Module: The module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'.
I've tried searching on the browser for fix but no solutions most of the queries.
Here is my function for connecting exchange online:
public static Task GetUserMailbox(string appId, string certificatePath, string certificatePassword, string organization, string userPrincipalName, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        // Set TLS protocol to 1.2
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        // Optionally bypass SSL certificate validation (not recommended for production)
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        // Load the certificate from the file using the password
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);

        var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
        iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;

        using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
        {
            remoteRunspace.Open(); // Ensure the Runspace is opened

            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

               

                // Import the Exchange Online module
                powershell.AddCommand("Import-Module")
                    .AddArgument("ExchangeOnlineManagement")
                    .Invoke();

                // Check for errors in Import-Module
                if (powershell.HadErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var error in powershell.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        log.LogError($"Error during Import-Module: {error}");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask; // Stop further execution if the module import fails
                }
                log.LogInformation("Successfully imported ExchangeOnlineManagement module.");

                // Clear the previous command
                powershell.Commands.Clear();

                // Connect to Exchange Online
                powershell.AddCommand("Connect-ExchangeOnline")
                    .AddParameter("AppId", appId)
                    .AddParameter("CertificateThumbprint", certificate.Thumbprint)
                    .AddParameter("Organization", organization)
                    .AddParameter("ShowBanner", false);
                powershell.Invoke();

                // Check for errors in Connect-ExchangeOnline
                if (powershell.HadErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var error in powershell.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        log.LogError($"Error during Connect-ExchangeOnline: {error}");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask; // Stop further execution if connection fails
                }
                log.LogInformation("Successfully connected to Exchange Online.");

                // Get user mailbox details using Get-CASMailbox and Select-Object
                powershell.Commands.Clear();
                powershell.AddCommand("Get-CASMailbox")
                    .AddParameter("Identity", userPrincipalName)
                    .AddCommand("Select-Object")
                    .AddParameter("Property", new string[] { "DisplayName", "UserPrincipalName", "ForwardingSmtpAddress", "OWAEnabled" });
                var mailboxResults = powershell.Invoke();

                // Check for errors in Get-CASMailbox
                if (powershell.HadErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var error in powershell.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        log.LogError($"Error during Get-CASMailbox: {error}");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask; // Stop if mailbox retrieval fails
                }

                // Display results
                if (mailboxResults != null && mailboxResults.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var result in mailboxResults)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation(result.ToString()); // Safely convert PSObject to string
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    log.LogInformation("No mailbox found or no results returned.");
                }

                // Disconnect from Exchange Online
                powershell.Commands.Clear();
                powershell.AddCommand("Disconnect-ExchangeOnline")
                    .AddParameter("Confirm", false);
                powershell.Invoke();

                // Check for errors in Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
                if (powershell.HadErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var error in powershell.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        log.LogError($"Error during Disconnect-ExchangeOnline: {error}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Successfully disconnected from Exchange Online.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Error Starts on importing module.
EDIT: Added importing powershell utiliy and this error comes:
Exception: Cannot find the built-in module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility' that is compatible with the 'Core' edition. Please make sure the PowerShell built-in modules are available. They usually come with the PowerShell package under the $PSHOME module path, and are required for PowerShell to function properly.
Im using sdk 7.4.5

The error is pretty explicit that it can't find a local install of PowerShell that's compatible with the 'Core' edition, i.e. you don't have PowerShell Core installed wherever this code is running.

Hi @MindSwipe, yes it was very explicit but very tricky on my end. I found at the locations where powershell is looking for module installations and all of them have existing module for the powershell utility. What I found is that the function app checks the module from elsewhere and not from the listed path given by the $env:PSModulePath -split ';' command. Modules that having error that cannot be loaded is existed as well on my project folder under runtime. Tried custom setting it to relative path to ensure that it'll be installed. to sum itup, functionapp uses different modulepath fr chkng

Did you try any other way of using Powershell with c#?

@RithwikBojja yes i try using console app and did not give me any issue at all. on this functionapp, gives me a lot of error and a lot of installation module required for it to be able to fully run. I ended up using powershell to deploy in functionapp,

As an alternative you can use System.Management.Automation module and code:
Function.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace FunctionApp232
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> ri_lg;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            ri_lg = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, The function started execution");
            var rith = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
            rith.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

            using var cho_ps = PowerShell.Create(rith);
            var rith_out = cho_ps.AddScript(@"

            Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Scope CurrentUser –Force
            Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser –Force
            Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
            Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

            Import-Module 'Az'
            Import-Module 'Az.Accounts'
            try{
            $rith_clnt_id = 828a057
            $rith_clnt_scret = XyG86cVj
            $rith_tnt_Id = 9329c02a-4f6d
            $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $rith_clnt_scret -AsPlainText -Force
            $rith = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $rith_clnt_id, $pwd
            Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $rith -Tenant $rith_tnt_Id
            New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'rithwik_test_rg' -Location 'West US 2'
                }
            catch {
             Write-Host 'Not created'
             }

            ").Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine(rith_out);    
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

I have used Service principal, you can use thumbprint or any other way login way.
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.4.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output:


For further information refer SO-Thread.
